# Flat surface not being shaded consistently across quads

Tags: 3d-view, lighting

I've been working on a mesh and realised that part of it is not being shaded consistently across the borders of each quad. I've isolated the section into its own blend file and cannot figure out what's causing the issue.

The section in question is a flat plane with some loop cuts. It's set to flat shading and the face normals are all consistent and pointing in the same direction. There is no modifiers applied.

[image: shading is not continuous across quads in a subdivided plane]

Does anyone know the cause of this and how to correct it?

Blend file can be downloaded here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DW8WcC2wAT3FR1h9uUGkHZmDef-mzgR3/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While deactivating the "Auto Smooth" helps at the moment, i believe that something else happened and messed the normals up.

In my humble opinion i think that the surface should be fine even if the **Normals** are set to "Auto Smooth", in that regard i checked and found that if you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> and use the "Set From Faces" option, the surface normals are corrected.

Here the visual confirmation:

[image]

Comment: I agree...  maybe something arround Alt+L...  haven't find what exactly.

Comment: Interesting. I tried using the set from faces on the full mesh, and whilst it fixed the section in question it also messed up the normals elsewhere on the mesh. However, selecting Reset Vectors fixed it for the whole mesh.

Comment: To figure out how it happened is i believe rather impossible, as just one shortcut pressed the wrong modifier key, like alt instead of shift, and it goes under. I just tried to play with the Alt+L function and somehow even got the result, but then again trying to replicate it did not work. I only remember that i switched on spherize and it looked like the situation we started with here. At the same time i found a bug, Blender crashes if you are in the Alt+L function and press Tabulator. Gonna write a bug report, so be careful to safe before playing with the Alt+L function!

Comment: All functions regarding Normals are working on the selected elements, so yeah, different situations like beveled areas and such can and will differ in result with different normal functions.

Comment: It's entirely possible I hit Alt+L by accident, as I was selecting connected vertices with L not long before I noticed the issue. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

*'Autosmooth'* is turned on:

Go to the *'object data properties'* part, in the *'normals'* section, and uncheck *'autosmooth'*.

[image]

Comment: No idea how I mangaged to turn that on. Thanks for the quick answer!